# Calculating the shortest path on a grid

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to calculate on a 2D array 8X8 grid all paths and have the algorithm go over all squares on the grid and configure the shortest path.

See code below:

```
public static int Mileage(int[,] arr, int x, int y, int miles)
{    
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 5 || y > 5 || arr[x, y] == 2) return 99; 
    if (arr[x, y] == 1) return miles;
    arr[x, y] = 2;
    miles++;
    Console.WriteLine(miles);
    int want2 = Math.Min(Mileage(arr, x - 1, y, miles), Mileage(arr, x + 1, y, miles));
    int want1 = Math.Min(Mileage(arr, x, y - 1, miles), Mileage(arr, x, y + 1, miles));
    return Math.Min(want1, want2);

}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Shortest path to what?

Comment: You need A* algorithm https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm